# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token (Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_CONTACT)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, declare, metatype

so i have defined the class with Qt creator (C++11) :

```
#ifndef CONTACT_H
#define CONTACT_H

#include <QStringList>
#include <list>

class Contact
{
public :
    Contact();
    ~Contact(); // destructeur

    Contact(const Contact & contact); // constructeur de copie
    Contact&  operator=(const  Contact& c); //opérateur de copie

    Contact( Contact && c); // constructeur de déplacement
    Contact&  operator=(Contact&& c); // opérateur de déplacement

    QString obtAdresse() const;
    void changeAdresse(QString adresse);

    QString obtFacebook() const;
    void changeFacebook(QString facebook);


    QString obtTwitter() const;
    void changeTwitter(QString twitter);

    QString obtNote() const;
    void changeNote(QString note);

    virtual  QString getnom() = 0;

    void reinitialise();

protected :
    QString adresse;
    QString facebook;
    QString twitter;
    QString note;

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Contact);

#endif // CONTACT_H
```

But i get this error :
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Contact);

Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 6):

You need to `#include <QMetaType>` because that is what defines the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro. Even if you do that though, the `Contact` class cannot be used like this because it has at least one pure virtual function (`getnom()`). It isn't exactly clear from [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE), but the class needs to be instantiable if you want to declare it as a meta type and if the class has a pure virtual function, it is not instantiable.

Answer (score -1):

Remove semicolon from the end of `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Contact);`.

Comment: I did this but i get this error ;expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'Contact'